# Font messed up in print, but looks good on the screen?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, printing, report

Okay, so I turned in this assignment a few days ago. It looked great on my machine (and I've had it tested on other machines too) but it looked DREADFUL once I printed it. The fist page, using bookman (provided by title.tex) looks fine, but the remaining pages (provided by main.tex) don't have the baskervald font properly embedded. This means the font was substitued by a default one (in the printer? The printer software?) and thereby losing it's proper spacing and ligatures...

I've enclosed something more than a MWE because I suspect maybe a package clash is to blame. The only noteworthy thing I left out below is the university title page, which was a PDF (that I had to fix up in Gimp).

I hope someone can tell me what went wrong -- I certainly don't want it to happen again!

**Compile chain:**

```
pdflatex title

pdflatex main
biber main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[style=historian,style=verbose-ibid,isbn=false,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{biblio.bib} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{%
  bibliography = {Litteraturliste},
  references = {Litteraturliste},
}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\small{\textsc{My Name\\Number: 12345}}}
\chead{\textbf{Exam\\Course}}
\rhead{\small{\textsc{My Number\\Afl. 20/1 2014}}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{27.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[bottom,flushmargin,hang,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{.5em}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{white}{}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{-\topskip}{0pt}[0pt]

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{title} 
\tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\raggedbottom
This here is the text. Here is a reference\footcite[19]{myt} and here is another\footcite[2]{oldstories}
\newpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Litteraturliste}
\printbibliography 

Brief final statement.
\end{document}
```

title.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\newcommand{\bigsize}{\fontsize{35pt}{20pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace{3em}
{\Huge \textsc{Course}}
\vspace{3em}
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{eck2}\\
\footnotesize{\textit{A pretty picture.}
\vfill
\begin{flushleft}
\large
My University\\
My Number\\
\vspace{1em}
My Name\\
Studienummer\\
Date
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

biblio.bib

```
@book{myt,
    address = {London},
    author = {Barthes, Roland},
    publisher = {Paladin Books},
    title = {Mythologies},
    translator = {{A}nnette {L}avers},
    year = {1986},
    note= {Første gang udgivet i 1957}
}

@inbook{oldstories,
    address = {New York og London},
    author = {Elkins, James},
    isbn = {9780415939430},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    title={Old Stories},
    booktitle = {Stories of {A}rt},
    pages={39-55},
    year = {2002}
}
```

**Edit:** Added output of pdffonts:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JJEBPO+URWBookmanL-Ligh              Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      19  0
GXGNTC+URWBookmanL-LighItal          Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      22  0
OWGWHH+BaskervaldADFStd-Bold         Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      34  0
BXKZQI+BaskervaldADFStd-Regular      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      35  0
FGJHAQ+BaskervaldADFStd-Italic       Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      38  0
BXKZQI+BaskervaldADFStd-Regular      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      48  0
```

Comment: it sounds like the fonts either aren't embedded, or are type 3 (bitmap) rather than type 1 (outline) fonts.  there are some other questions that have addressed that; i'm just not in a position to retrieve them at the moment.

Comment: When I compile your code, correcting the missing curly bracket (please check your code compiles before posting it!), all of the fonts are embedded. You can test this by using the Properties dialogue in your PDF viewer or running `pdffonts <filename>.pdf` to check. That's where you should start. Other than that, I could only imagine it being a printing issue or that there is something screwed up about your installation of `baskervald`.

Comment: It compiles here without a hitch, what missing bracket are we talking about?

Also, I suspected a printer error at first, but when another printer got it wrong too -- using *another* "default font" for substitution of baskervald, I started to think it was indeed the file...

Comment: While creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it can happen, that the issue disappears – and this one of the possible goals of this process.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but as stated previously, this is mainly out of curiosity as to what went wrong. Call it research, if you will.