# newtxtext typewriter text OK on screen but does not print (sometimes)

Tags: fonts, printing, typewriter, newtx

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

Hello world
\texttt{Hello world}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with just-updated TeX Live 2015 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3. `newtx` is version 1.466.

```
pdflatex problem.tex
```

The PDF looks correct on screen in all three of Skim 1.4.18, Preview 8.1 (877.7), and Acrobat Pro 11.0.15:

[image: ok]

However, when the PDF is printed with Skim or Preview on a Canon C5240A copier, the typewriter text characters are missing:

[image: fail]

Printing with Acrobat Pro to the same copier, or with Skim to an HP 4650 printer, works fine.

Clearly, I'm running into some kind of driver or printer issue, and while I know how to print it OK for myself, I can't control which viewers and printers readers will choose. Further, they will have much less patience for problems.

**Is there anything I can do to diagnose this issue and make it print reliably with diverse viewers and printers?**

I realize that there are some similar questions that have been closed as off-topic (e.g., [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155492) [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203451)). I'm hoping mine is on-topic because it is "given this situation, what can I do next" rather than "how do I fix my OS/printer".

`pdffonts` output is follows:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
RVTVDF+TeXGyreTermes-Regular         Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
GHKXIW+t1xtt                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed question.  Can you provide version numbers for your OS X, etc. etc.